# Select keyword cant be inserted in to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql database for an application. I get some user details. Once user uses `select` keyword in his answer, the Insert query causes problems in mysql. I am using nearly 300 insert queries in my over all application. Select keyword makes problem.

How to solve it in easy way?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATED:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `feedback_entry_mailactivity_log` (  `subject`, `body_text`, `to_mail_id`, `from_mail_id`, `cc_mail_id`, `created_user_id`, `created_date_time`, `last_updated_user_id`, `last_updated_date_time`, `feedback_entry_id`, `feedback_id`, `account_id`, `section_id`)
                    VALUES ('".$subject."', '".$body_text."','".$to_mail_id."','".$from_mail_id."','".$cc_mail_id."','".$assign_to_userid."', NOW(),'".$assign_to_userid."', NOW(),'".$feedback_entry_id."','".$feedback_id."','".$this->account_id."','".$temp_sectionid."' );";
        $this->db->execute($query);
```

In this case if `$subject="select a tag";`

Thus when I use keyword select insert query doesn't works

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Can you please re-write your issue, and provide details (including code examples)?

Comment: Please post the offending line of code.

Comment: I bet 20¢ it's mod_security blocking it or a simpleminded badwords filter in the forgotten mysql query wrapper.

Comment: how to solve this @mario

Comment: With getting my problem all of u gifted me negative vote. :-( I didnt need votes i need solution

Comment: @Mohan: That is not a good way to do the query; what if the user puts in single quotes in `$body_text` (for example)?  The code you posted has a SQL injection vulnerability that will let people break into your Web site.

Comment: @Mohan: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (or search for "prepared statement PHP") to find out the proper way to do these queries.

Comment: Why select keyword is not accepted in mysql. please say some simple solution to solve this with my example query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is the use of string-generated SQL statement** -- this can lead to incorrect escaping and injection attacks (or mis-behaviors) leading to errors like above. Imagine if one of the input variables -- the one with 'SELECT' in it -- contains the SQL string-escape character such as `Wish this would' SELECT FAIL`. (This might not be the exact problem in this case and the real problem could lay with some other layer trying to "protect" the use of the bad access method(s).)

To fix this problem *correctly* use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (or similar) and [prepared-statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). (Jeremiah Willcock suggested [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)).

> > The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).

Note: **Incorrect "solutions"** include [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and similar. There are very few -- perhaps none for static DQL -- cases when "manual escaping with SQL string-building" approaches like this should be used.

Happy coding.